# Typescript ES7 descriptors with ES3 output?

Tags: javascript, typescript

After looking through the issues it seems TS *should* support ES3 with decorators, and I have a scenario where I have an existing codebase in typescript which uses decorators and targets ES5 but I now need to apparently support IE6 which requires ES3.

Now according to:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4681

It seems that ES3 should be supported, but if I output to target ES3 I get:

`error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

I get 0 errors and everything works in ES5, so do you need to do anything to get it working in ES3 or is it just not supported?

Here is a cloud 9 example of the issue:

https://ide.c9.io/grofit/knockout-decorators-es3-example

just run `gulp` on the command line, if you change the tsconfig target to es5 it will work.

Comment: can you provide code? did you try `tsc script.ts -t ES3`?

Comment: Sure, I am using tsconfig and gulp typescript with an es3 target. I have added a link to a cloud9 version showing the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like when you target ES3, method decorators are not properly supported, or not supported at all. Unfortunately, the error message you get isn't super helpful. Looks like there was some [discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4741) about the error message. Also, it isn't clear to me if they intended partial support for decorators when targeting ES3 or full support.

For example, if you try to use a method decorator targeting ES3:

```
function myMethodDecorator(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> {
    // do something
    return descriptor;
};

class MyClass {
    @myMethodDecorator
    myMethod(arg: string) { 
        return "Message -- " + arg;
    }
}
```

You get the error message you reported:

> error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
>     Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

But if you try to apply a property descriptor, despite the fact that you are applying it to a method, the compiler is strangely OK with that. This compiles targeting ES3 without errors:

```
function myPropertyDecorator(target: Object, propertyKey: string): void {
    // something
};

class MyClass {
    @myPropertyDecorator
    myMethod(arg: string) { 
        return "Message -- " + arg;
    }
}
```

However, you can get it to compile to ES3 when using method decorators by:

```
let myMethodDecorator: any = function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> {
    // do something
    return descriptor;
};

class MyClass {
    @myMethodDecorator
    myMethod(arg: string) { 
        return "Message -- " + arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, I am out of the office atm so when I get back in I will verify and give you the answer

Comment: Thanks. I am interested to find out if it works in IE6. Looking at the emitted code, it appears to depend on `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`. So you might have to shim that method if possible.

Comment: hmm so I can get it compile using the above like you suggest, problem is it just complains that descriptor is undefined, so it seems when targetting es6 it does not pass in the descriptor so there is nothing to hook into the method with. In my "real" world scenario I am also passing args to the decorator so it wraps the internal decorator. Odd thing is in ES5 target it outputs and works fine with same code, so something in the output must be off... I am testing currently in FF I am only planning on testing in IE6 when both output targets work on FF.

Comment: I was messing with it this weekend, and I found the same thing. When transpiled for es3 you get a line like this: `__decorate([log], MyClass.prototype, "myMethod");`. When targeting es5 you get `__decorate([log], MyClass.prototype, "myMethod", null);`. That `null` parameter is the only difference, and that causes it to fail. But there are actually worse problems. The transpiled output still makes use of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` which doesn't exist in ES3, and is problematic to polyfill in IE: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim#may-fail

Comment: Hang on... I think I have it. Will post in a few minutes.

Comment: OK. Got it. The reason it fails in FF is because FF supports ES5, and specifically `Reflect`. If you look at the transpiled code for the `__decorate()` function, you'll see what I mean. All that to say, when you target ES3 it generates output that is incompatible with ES5. This seems like a bug in the compiler. You would need to compile your scripts for both ES3 and ES5, then detect the ECMA Script version being used by the browser, and load the appropriate script.

Comment: Incidentally, even though the ES3 output uses `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` it is never called. So, you won't need to polyfill it.

Comment: And even after all that it still fails to pass `descriptor` to the method decorator function when targeting ES3. So it appears that support for method decorators isn't not yet implemented when you target ES3.

Comment: Seriously thanks for taking the time out to help research all this for me. In an ideal world I would not need IE6 support so I guess it seems at the moment I will just have to not use decorators. It is not the end of the world as I am already having to pluck out some ES5 stuff (getters and setters for observables). I will give you the answer as I think you have shown that it is not usable even if it does compile.